# Why does Horspool not work on binaries?

Tags: c, algorithm, search

I'm trying to make a quick and simple signature detection program in C. It should read a binary file (.exe, ELF, a library, etc...) and search for binary data (sometimes strings, sometimes bytes);

I have a simple test program in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const char *str = "TestingOneTwoThree";

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s %ld\n", str, (long)getpid());
        sleep(1);
    }

}
```

Here is the horspool algorithm I'm using. I adapted it directly from the wikipedia pseudocode found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define HORSPOOL_COUNT 256
#define BLOCK_SIZE 1024
#define MAX(a, b) a > b ? a : b

ssize_t horspool_find(const char *buf, size_t buflen, const char *egg, size_t egglen)
{
    int table[HORSPOOL_COUNT];
    ssize_t shift = 0, i, tmp;

    for(i = 0; i < HORSPOOL_COUNT; ++i)
    {
        table[i] = (int)egglen;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < egglen - 1; ++i)
    {
        table[(int)egg[i]] = egglen - i - 1;
    }

    while(shift <= buflen - egglen)
    {
        i = egglen - 1;
        while(buf[shift + i] == egg[i])
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                return shift;
            }
            i--;
        }
        shift += MAX(1, table[(int)buf[shift + egglen - 1]]);
    }
    return -1;
}

char *readfile(const char *filename, size_t *size)
{
    int ch;
    size_t used = 0, allocated = 0;
    char *buf = NULL, *tmp = NULL;
    FILE *f;

    if((f = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL)
    {
        if(size) *size = 0;
        return perror("fopen"), NULL;
    }

    while((ch=fgetc(f)) != EOF)
    {
        if(used >= allocated)
        {
            allocated += BLOCK_SIZE;
            tmp = realloc(buf, allocated);
            if(tmp == NULL)
            {
                free(buf);
                if(size) *size = 0;
                fclose(f);
                return perror("realloc"), NULL;
            }
            buf = tmp;
        }
        buf[used++] = (char)ch;
    }

    fclose(f);
    if(size) *size = used;
    return realloc(buf, used);
}

ssize_t naivealg_find(const char *buf, size_t buflen, const char *find, size_t findlen)
{
    size_t i, j, diff = buflen - findlen;
    for(i = 0; i < diff; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < findlen; ++j)
        {
            if(buf[i+j] != find[j])
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(j == findlen)
        {
            return (ssize_t)i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    size_t size;
    char *buf = readfile("./a.out", &size);
    char *pat = "TestingOneTwoThree";
    ssize_t pos1 = horspool_find(buf, size, pat, strlen(pat));
    ssize_t pos2 = naivealg_find(buf, size, pat, strlen(pat));
    fprintf(stdout, "Offsets: %zd ~ %zd\n", pos1, pos2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is something along the lines of:

`Offsets: -1 ~ 2052`

Notes:

- The same buffer and "egg" work with the naive search implementation.
- The horspool implementation seems to work correctly with normal strings as the `buf` and `egg` parameters.

Comment: Why is signed `ssize_t shift` and not `size_t shift`?

Comment: Recommend   `while(shift <= buflen - egglen)` --> `while(shift + egglen <= buflen)` to avoid underflow.

Comment: The return value is `ssize_t` because it returns `-1` if the pattern is not found.

Comment: I was not asking about the return value, just, `ssize_t shift`.

Comment: The only reason it was signed was to be consistent with the return type.

Comment: You say it doesn't work for binary _files_, but you have not shown any code that reads a file.  How do you know that the problem is in your `horspool_find()` function and not in how you read the file?  Depending on the operating system and libraries that you use, something may be trying to interpret your binary file as some kind of encoded text.

Comment: I know this because changing the shift to `shift += 1` (i.e. without using the table offsets at all) it detects the occurrence at the correct position. As for the file reading, I don't think the code is really relevant, but I'd be happy to post it if it will help.

Comment: "but I cannot get it to work for binary files." I suspect they ( `buf,  buflen, egg,  egglen`) are not set up correctly prior to the  `horspool_find()` call.

Comment: Updated with full example @james large.

Comment: `if((f = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)` --> `if((f = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL)` when doing binary.

Comment: How do you know `"TestingOneTwoThree"` is in `a.out`?  Just because it is in the source code does not mean it must appear like that in `a.out`.

Comment: I change it to `"rb"`, but that still seems like it's besides the point. It works with naive, but not with horspool.

Comment: @chux a.out is the compiled binary of the top source code. `const char *str = "TestingOneTwoThree";` And again, **the pattern is discovered at the correct location using the naive algorithm on the same buffer**. It absolutely does exist in the binary.

Comment: Try `MAX(a, b) a > b ? a : b` --> `MAX(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))` to insure operator precedence.

Comment: @chux good point, but did not seem to work.

Comment: Likely not for this test case as `egg` is ASCII,  but `table[(int)egg[i]]` --> `table[(unsigned char)egg[i]] = egglen - i - 1;` to avoid negative indexes into `table[]`.

Comment: @chux that worked! Thank you!

Comment: Don't post answers in your question. Post them as answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code was using a signed `char` and with binary data, from time to time, would index incorrectly with a negative index.

```
// table[(int)buf[shift + egglen - 1]]
table[(unsigned char )buf[shift + egglen - 1]]
```

---

This problem also exists in the the `egg` pattern.

```
// table[(int) egg[i]] = egglen - i - 1;
table[(unsigned char) egg[i]] = egglen - i - 1;
```

Other sign issues occur when `buflen < egglen`

```
// while (shift <= buflen - egglen)
// change to avoid underflow
while (shift + egglen <= buflen)
```

---

Also consider opening the file in binary and:

```
ssize_t shift,i; --> size_t shift,i;

int table[HORSPOOL_COUNT]; -- > size_t table[HORSPOOL_COUNT];
```

Add `()`s to `#define MAX(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))`